# Reset tap Counter WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, counter, reset

I'm developing an wp8 Application that requires a number of taps to get to another page but I want the counter to reset if the user presses another button. here is my three buttons and the counter works fine i just want it to reset if another button is tapped. The problem I'm having is that once one button is tapped the other button counters go up as well and I even made 3 counters, one for each button and yet the counter still goes up even if i press one button once, press another button once and go back to the first button pressed the counter hasn't reset. Is there a way that if one button is pressed and another button is pressed that the first buttons counter will reset if another button is pressed. Thanks

```
    private void Instructions_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            TapCount++;
        if (TapCount == 2)
        {
              NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/instructions.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }

        else
        {
            SayWords("You have selected the Instructions");

        }

    }


    private void Settings_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TapCount++;

        if (TapCount == 2)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Settings.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }


        else
        {
            SayWords("You have selected the Settings");

        }
    }


    private void CreateMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TapCount++;
        if (TapCount == 2)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ctmessage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            SayWords("You have selected the Create Message");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are saying that you want the counter to be resetted but you're actually not doing it.
Add this method to your class:

```
private object previousSender;
private void CheckSender(object sender)
{
    if (sender != previousSender)
    {
        TapCount = 0;
    }

    previousSender = sender;
}
```

and call it at the start of each Click method you have.

This will check if the sender is the same button as before, if not it reset the TapCount.